# Doctest letter extraction

Tags: python, text-extraction, doctest

Extract all the unique letters present in the text string.
:param text: string data
:return: a tuple of all the unique letters of the string in lowercase

```
 def extract_letters(text):
    """
        Extract all the unique letters present in the text string.
        :param text: string data
        :return: a tuple of all the unique letters of the string in lowercase
        >>> extract_letters("Python 123 is C00!_")
        ('p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'i', 's', 'c')
        >>> extract_letters("Numbers Are Overrated!")
        ('n', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', 's', 'a', 'o', 'v', 't', 'd')
    """
    letters = []
    users = []
    
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if (text[i]).isalpha():
            letters.append(text[i].lower())
    
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        if letters[i] not in users:
            users.append(letters[i])
    
    return (users)
```

Was wondering if there was a way to make the output curved brackets instead of square brackets so it matches and the doctest completes?

Comment: Please note that the assignment asks for you to return a tuple, not a list.  Tuples are printed with curved brackets.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Roberts I did not put the tuple in front of the (users) in the return

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def extract_letters(text):
    """
        Extract all the unique letters present in the text string.
        :param text: string data
        :return: a tuple of all the unique letters of the string in lowercase
        >>> extract_letters("Python 123 is C00!_")
        ('p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'i', 's', 'c')
        >>> extract_letters("Numbers Are Overrated!")
        ('n', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', 's', 'a', 'o', 'v', 't', 'd')
    """
    letters = []
    users = []
    
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if (text[i]).isalpha():
            letters.append(text[i].lower())
    
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        if letters[i] not in users:
            users.append(letters[i])
    
    return tuple((users)) #returns result converted from list to tuple.
```